# Ubuntu 16.4, Java, WAV file playback

Tags: java, ubuntu, wav

This is a weird thing. I'm trying to playback some sounds via Java AudioSystem and `AudioSystem.getClip()`. The files are all "PCM_SIGNED, 22.050.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little endian".

On several Ubuntu 16.4 LTS Linux boxes this format is rejected by PulseAudio with an `Invalid Format Exception`, because the only accepted format is seemingly "PCM_SIGNED, unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big endian".

I already tried to re-sample my WAVs in order to match this strange constraint, to no avail. Those are not even accepted anymore by `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()`

Needless to say, that the same works fine on Mac OS and Windows. And there is also no problem to playback these files using the `sox` library and `play file.wav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved.

Usually if one asks, how to playback WAV using Java, this is the most common answer:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(DragonflyApp.class.getResource("/resources/" + soundFile));
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.addLineListener(e -> {
    if (e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        // Do something on end of playback
    }
});
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();
```

Unfortunately on some Linux systems this ends up in an "Invalid Format" exception, thrown by PulseAudio, which claims to be unable to playback the simplest WAV file (see above).

The workaround is to use this sequence under Linux instead. It generally does also work on MacOS, but the final "STOP" indication comes very late (roughly 5s after playback end), so I make a conditional execution here:

This works on Linux (at least on Ubunutu 16.04) with clips, which have formerly been rejected by PulseAudio:

```
DataPusher datapusher = null;
DataLine.Info lineinfo = null;
SourceDataLine sourcedataline = null;
lineinfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioInputStream.getFormat());
if (!(AudioSystem.isLineSupported(lineinfo))) {
    return;
}
sourcedataline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(lineinfo);
sourcedataline.addLineListener(e -> {
    if (e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        // Do something on end of playback
    }
});
datapusher = new DataPusher(sourcedataline, audioInputStream);
datapusher.start();
```

Both code snippets are used conditionally:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X")) {
    // The clip solution
}
else {
    // The datapusher solution
}
```

Hope, that helps others, who will also have this problem.